# Grep continues despite apparent non-match

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have a file with lines that all have the same pattern:

```
Word word word word,more words here,0-9 more words here
```

I want to find the lines where the first set of words before the first comma is 20 characters or more. I wrote

```
cat file.txt | grep -E "^[A-Z,a-z,[:space:]]{20,}[,]{1}"
```

I would think that this would look for a new line marker, then for a series of words of 20 characters or more, then for exactly one comma, and stop. The words after shouldn't count because there is no new line marker there.

But this matches the second string of words after the comma as well. Why would this be?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: To answer the why question. It is because `grep` is greedy by default when matching BRE (basic) and ERE (extended regular expressions).  Your regex needs to be modified to do a non-greedy match.

Comment: @fpmurphy Thank you for your reply. Do you know how I could fix it?

Comment: Part of the issue is that the subpattern `[A-Z,a-z]` is not just "any capital or lowercase letters", but also is "or any commas".

Comment: Your example is not 20 characters but 18.   Try the following `grep -Eo '^[^,]{18,} file.txt` or `grep -Eo '^[A-Za-z[:space:]]{18,}' file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

`[A-Z,a-z,[:space:]]` matches on one collating element (which can be more than one character) that sorts between `A` and `Z` in the locale's collation order or is the `,` character or sorts between `a` and `z` or is the `,` character or is a character classified as whitespace in the locale.

To match any one character other than `,`, it's just `[^,]`. To match on a character that is classified as word character or whitespace, it's `[[:alpha:][:space:]]` (to which you may want to add `_` to be equivalent to the `[\w\s]` of perl regexps). To match on ASCII letters or ASCII whitespace, if your shell supports `$'...'`, it's `$'[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \t\r\f\v]'`¹.

So:

```
<file.txt grep -E '^[^,]{20,},'
```

To match on lines starting with 20 or more non-`,` characters followed by `,`.

`grep` (whose name comes from the `g/regular expression/p` command in `ed`) prints the lines that match the pattern. To print only the matched portions in those lines, with some `grep` implementations, you can add the `-o` option (originally from GNU `grep`). Some can also print the matched portion a different colour when sent to a terminal that supports colours.

Beware though that with those `-o` / `--color`, `grep` attempts to match the regex several times, repeating the search on the portion of the line after the end of the previous match. You'll find that some implementations of `grep` don't do it properly. For instance, with the `grep` from ast-open:

```
$ echo aaa | grep -o '^a'
a
a
a
```

That's because it did find `a` at the start of the line, and then carried on looking for more matches by applying the `^a` regex on `aa`, the remaining of the line and so on. GNU and busybox `grep` don't have the problem.

(note that `cat` is the command to con`cat`enate files, you don't need it here).

---

<sup>¹ In ASCII, there's also *line feed* aka `\n`, newline `^J` usually classified as whitespace, but that cannot appear in the contents of a line since that's the line delimiter, and it has a special meaning in arguments to `grep` where one can use it to separate several regexps to match on the lines, so we don't want to include it here</sup>